# WHM server access logs for all accounts

Tags: linux, debugging, ssh, cpanel, lamp

I've had a lot of issues with hacks and DDOS attacks on a few servers, though this is usually caused by some very simple things. However I've found it invaluable to be able to look through an accounts access logs and list the hit pages in order of lowest to highest using the following through ssh `cat example.co.uk | cut -d\" -f2 | awk '{print $1 " " $2}' | cut -d? -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

However this means I need to run this against every single accounts access log. is there a server wide version or script out there to scan all access logs for activity?

Comment: Access logs = acces to cpanel? acces logs = acces or Apache's log to domains?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your command in for loop to check all domain access logs file.

```
for i in `cat /etc/trueuserdomains | awk {'print $1'} | cut -d":" -f1`;do echo "Pages list Of $i" ; cat /usr/local/apache/domlogs/$i* | grep GET | cut -d\" -f2 | awk '{print $1 " " $2}' | cut -d? -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n;done > /root/report.txt
```

Once it's done, Please check your **/root/report.txt** file.